# Make call and handle call with php

Tags: php

I need some information 
Is a way to php can handle a call ?
i want to write an app that When i receive a call ،play a sound for introduce part of my 
company  and after that found what key was pressed to i Transfer to that part

for example user call to my company and after that select to what part he want to connect

i want to divert a call too ,

so please give me some information about which programming language can handle this ?
can php do this?

i search about  this subject but nothing found

Comment: have you tried asterisk?

Comment: It does look like a chat application to me. Go through this anyway http://stackoverflow.com/a/4640631/1172872 or may be http://www.voicent.com/devnet/docs/phpapi.htm & http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/twilio-phone-call/

Comment: @DevZer0 i heard about that what is that exactly ? i heard asterisk is for making voip call can you explain more ?

Comment: @sk8terboi87ツ no its about calling with telephone or mobile not a chat app

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PHP can work with that type of networking hardware. Things you want to do requires real and practical networking knowledge along with linux and programming

Try asking this question on serverfault or [here](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com)

There are many questions on serverfault similar to this.

Also check this out, it is a ruby framework but there is a way to make it work with PHP and it is for web developers
[Adhearsion](http://adhearsion.com/)

Or if you don't have any background in this area hire CISCO but learning yourself is cool